# How to invoke Special Auto Updater via CustomAutoUpdater in ArcFM

Tags: arccatalog, arcfm, arcgis-10.8

I am trying to invoke `SpecialAU`(Auto-Updater) `ArcFM` with below mentioned code, but I am not able to trigger it since it is not available in ArcFM AU Assigner window (Object Info).

I took help from
http://gisstudycenter.blogspot.com/2015/01/arcfm-auto-updaters-to-update-shape.html

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using Miner.ComCategories;
using Miner.Interop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace DesktopClassLibrary2
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("fecebee8-67a5-47ad-a1a7-314ba50b2c9c")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("DesktopClassLibrary2.Class1")]
    [ComponentCategory(ComCategory.SpecialAutoUpdateStrategy)]
    public class Class1 : IMMSpecialAUStrategyEx
    {
        void IMMSpecialAUStrategyEx.Execute(IObject pObject, mmAutoUpdaterMode eAUMode, mmEditEvent eEvent)
        {
            int n = pObject.OID;
            IObjectClass objClass = pObject.Class;
            IFeatureLayer fl = new FeatureLayer
            {
                FeatureClass = objClass as IFeatureClass
            };
            eAUMode = mmAutoUpdaterMode.mmAUMArcCatalog;
        }

        string IMMSpecialAUStrategyEx.Name => "class1";

        public bool get_Enabled(IObjectClass pObjectClass, mmEditEvent eEvent)
        {
            return eEvent == mmEditEvent.mmEventFeatureCreate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first register my AU with the help of this command in post-build event in Visual Studio.

```
RegX.exe "$(TargetPath)" /r /c /s /d
```

`(TargetPath)` is an installation path and can be configured with Edit Post-Build >> macro.

[image]